# Proof that $W^{\perp\perp}=W$ (in a finite dimensional vector space)

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the field $K$, with a non-degenerate scalar product. Let $W$ be a subspace. Show that $W^{\perp\perp}=W$.

I have no idea how to solve this one. Since I am self-studying I have no way to know if I get this right, that is the reason I ask for a resolution.

**Questions**:

Can someone provide me a resolution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, according to the definition;
$$
W^{\perp}=\{u\in V:u\cdot v=0, \forall v\in W\}\Longrightarrow W^{\perp \perp}=\{u\in V:u\cdot v=0, \forall v\in W^{\perp}\}
$$
Let $w \in W$, then we have that  $w \cdot v=0, \forall v\in W^{\perp} \Longrightarrow w\in W^{\perp \perp}\Longrightarrow W \subset W^{\perp \perp}$
On the other hand, we have that;
$$
V=W^{\perp}\oplus W=W^{\perp \perp}\oplus W^{\perp}\Longrightarrow \dim(W)=\dim(W^{\perp \perp})
$$
Taking everything into account;
$$
(\dim(W)=\dim(W^{\perp \perp})) \wedge (W \subset W^{\perp \perp}) \Longleftrightarrow W^{\perp \perp}=W
$$

Answer (score 1):

Just show set equality, i.e $W^{\perp \perp} \subseteq W$ and,$W \subseteq W^{\perp \perp}$ .

For example Let $x \in W$, Let $y\in W^{\perp}$, then $\langle x,y \rangle  =0$, hence since $y$ arbitrary, $x\in W^{\perp \perp}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $U\subseteq V$ be a subspace and $u_1, \dots, u_n$ be a orthogonal basis of $U$ and define

$$ P: V \rightarrow V, \ P(v)=\sum_{j=1}^n \langle v, u_j \rangle u_j.$$

Show that $\operatorname{Ker}(P)=U^{\perp}$ and $\operatorname{Im}(P)=U$. Thus, by the rank-nulity theorem we have

$$ \dim(V)=\dim(U)+\dim(U^{\perp}).$$

Using this equality for $U=W, W^{\perp}$, we get

$$ \dim(W)=\dim(W^{\perp \perp}).$$

Therefore, it suffices to check that $W\subseteq W^{\perp \perp}$. Let $w\in W$ and $u\in W^{\perp}$, then we have

$$ \langle w, v\rangle =0.$$

As $v\in W^{\perp}$ arbitrary, we get $w\in W^{\perp \perp}$. As $w\in W$ arbitrary, we conclude

$$ W\subseteq W^{\perp \perp}.$$

As they have the same dimension, they are equal.

Comment: Should it be this way $P: V \rightarrow V, \ P(v)=\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\langle v, u_j \rangle}{\langle u_j, u_j \rangle} u_j$ ? Should not it be $v\in W^{\perp}$? Once you use$ v$ on the inner product $\langle w,v\rangle=0$.

Comment: @PedroGomes The normalisation is not necessary. As the $u_j$ are linearly independend, you have $P(v)=0$ iff $\langle v, u_j\rangle $ for all $j$. Therefore, $ \operatorname{Ker}(P)=U^{\perp}$. However, it would be easier to see that $\operatorname{Im}(P)=U$ if I would choose the $u_j$ to be orthogonal. I'll edit this way.