# Vector subspace and it's orthocomplement

Tags: linear-algebra

Let S_n be a vector subspaces and O(S_n) is defined as the orthocomplement of S_n i.e the collection of all vectors which are orthogonal to S_n.Then show that O(O(S_n))=S_n .

What I am trying to do is to show that S_n subset of O(O(S_n)) again O(O(S_n)) is subset of S_n .Then we are done but don't know how to show this with the help of basis of S_n and O(S_n).

Comment: Possibly helpful: [Proof that $W^{\perp\perp}=W$ (in a finite dimensional vector space)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2352691/proof-that-w-perp-perp-w-in-a-finite-dimensional-vector-space).

Comment: I had tried in this way but fail to do so.