# Showing existence of vectors and scalars

Tags: linear-algebra

I was thinking about a problem:

Let $V$ be an $m$-dimensional affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $m < n$. Show
that there exist linearly independent vectors $\textbf{a}_1, ..., \textbf{a}_{n−m}$, and scalars $b_1, ..., b_{n−m}$, such that $V=\{\textbf{y} | \textbf{a}_i^T \textbf{y} = b_i, i=1,2, \ldots, n-m\}$.

Is my approach (in the following) reasonable?

If $V$ be an affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then there is a vector $\textbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $V=\textbf{v}+U$ for some subspace $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ having same dimension as $V$ i.e. $m$. This can be seen from Proposition 2.21 [here](https://jp-g.de/WS18-19/Lecture04.pdf).

Let $U^{\perp}$ be the orthogonal complement of $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ w.r.t the Euclidean inner product. It has dimension $n-m$. Take a basis of $U^{\perp}$ as $\textbf{a}_1, ..., \textbf{a}_{n−m}$.

Since we have (as $U$ is a finite dimensional) $U^{\perp \perp} = U$ (from [Proof that $W^{\perp\perp}=W$ (in a finite dimensional vector space)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2352691/proof-that-w-perp-perp-w-in-a-finite-dimensional-vector-space)) then we can say $U = \{\textbf{y} | \textbf{w}^T \textbf{y} = 0, \forall \textbf{w} \in U^{\perp}\}$. Since $\textbf{a}_1, ..., \textbf{a}_{n−m}$ is a basis of $U^{\perp}$ hence we can alternatively say $U = \{\textbf{y} | \textbf{a}_i^T \textbf{y} = 0, \forall i \in \{1,2,\ldots, n-m\} \}$.

Since $V=\textbf{v} + U$, we can say now $V = \{\textbf{y} + \textbf{v} | \textbf{a}_i^T \textbf{y} = 0, \forall i \in \{1,2,\ldots, n-m\} \}$, or in other words (by shifting by $\textbf{v}$), $V = \{\textbf{y} | \textbf{a}_i^T \textbf{y} = b_i, \forall i \in \{1,2,\ldots, n-m\} \}$ where I have set $b_i=\textbf{a}_i^T\textbf{v}$. Is that correct?

Comment: Affine spaces are not always vector spaces as they are not required to contain the zero vector. You'll need to address this explicitly.

Comment: I don't see how affine spaces are coming here. I did not claim anything about affine spaces. Is my claim above true?

Comment: @SoumyaGanguly absolutely not. You're arguing about vector spaces and $V$ is affine. You can't use basis vectors, the orthogonal compliment theorem, or the inner product. You must address the origin problem first.

Comment: Ok I got what you are saying.

Comment: I changed my answer. Is that correct now? @CyclotomicField ?

Comment: Looks great now. The trick of moving it to the origin, arguing a vector space, then moving the origin back is thematic for affine spaces. Notationally I like to call it $v_0$ instead of $v$ to highlight that it's a new origin but that's just a personal preference.

Comment: Thanks everyone !